# Why do only a few English demonyms indicate gender?

Tags: demonyms, grammatical-gender

A friend recently pondered why *Latino/Latina* inflects according to gender. I suggested that it's because *Latino* is a [loanword from a language with grammatical gender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender#Gender_in_English), but he found it odd that other demonyms don't inflect this way, and he wondered whether there was something etymologically or historically unique about the word. Wikipedia offers a [long list of demonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym), and only *Pinoy/Pinay* and *Canadien(ne)* inflect like this.

I also noted that *Englishman* has a feminine *‑woman* form, although the etymology here is different. [Etymology Online](http://etymonline.com/index.php?search=Englishman) attests that *Englishman* dates to Old English, whereas gendered *Englishwoman* is a newer form (c.1400). This inflection appears to have a different productive mechanism, one that mainly applies to places with significant Anglophone or Norse history: *Englishman, Frenchman, Irishman, Dutchman, Scotsman, Chinaman, Welshman, Norseman* ([roughly in order of usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Englishman,Frenchman,Irishman,Dutchman,Scotsman,Chinaman,Welshman,Norseman&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)).

Is there any etymological rhyme or reason to this? Why do we inflect *Latino* and *Canadien* but not other words derived from non-Germanic languages like [*Spaniard*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?search=spaniard)? Why do we have *Irishwomen* but not *Italianwomen* (and only very rarely *Spanishwomen*)?

---

**Update:** MετάEd answered this satisfactorily for the native demonyms ending in *-man*: In those cases, the gendered variants are largely the result of a semantic shift where Old English *man* “person” became Middle English *man* “male” and *woman* “female.” However, I'm still looking for an explanation of why English adopted the gender inflection of *Latino, Filipino, and Pinoy,* unlike most other demonyms. Is this perhaps because they are endonyms used by a significant number of bilingual English speakers?

Comment: Conversely, why do we have _an Italian_ and _a Scot,_ but _an English_ or _an Irish_ sounds awkward?

Comment: see: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104508/is-it-acceptable-to-use-womyn-or-womin-instead-of-women

Comment: @MετάEd Sorry, I'm not seeing the relationship between _womyn_ and this issue, other than that they both touch on gender. It is puzzling though that a recent English coinage (Etymonline dates _Latino_ to 1946) would borrow gender when the linguistic and social trend has been to move away from grammatical gender.

Comment: @MετάEd I think I see what you were getting at now – the etymology of _woman,_ which makes that case a bit different from loanwords like _fiancé(e)_ and _blond(e)._

Comment: "Pinoy/Pinay" --- and "Filipino/Filipina" of course.

Comment: +1 Excellent question; perhaps stands a better chance of finding great answer(s) on linguistics.

Comment: Do we inflect *Canadien*? I'd be more inclined to call them all *Canadians*. Quebecois may feel differently of course.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I grew up near English-speaking Ontario, where _Canadian_ is common and _Canadien_ would probably seem affected unless you're talking about the hockey team. It wouldn't surprise me to see it in reference to French Canadians like William Shatner and Celine Dion, especially if somebody wanted to make a point of calling her _Canadienne._

Comment: @AndrewLeach I thought [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Latina%2CFilipina%2CCanadienne&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) showed that _Canadienne_ is nearly as common as _Filipina_ – but it's mostly French text, not English. (Likewise for early usage of _Latina,_ which mostly appears in Latin phrases like _Biblia Latina._)

Comment: @Kris Thanks for the tip. I asked about the _-man_ part of the question on Linguistics.SE: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/why-do-only-a-few-english-demonyms-have-a-man-suffix

Comment: First because almost no English speakers know that the term exists… which being the case, why would the language itself not reflect their combination of ignorance and disinterest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spanish has a fairly simple system of indicating gender agreement that is familiar to a great many English speakers (maybe most), which means English speakers are more likely to be aware of how to inflect Spanish adjectives for gender than adjectives from most other languages.

Even though French gender agreement is also relatively simple—mostly a matter of adding "e"—the resulting forms  would often be homophonous if read using English conventions, which I think leads to more confusion. The French-derived words that are inflected in writing in English, such as *né(e)* and *fiancé(e),* are fairly often misspelled.

Additionally, the word "Latino/Latina" entered English relatively recently, so it's had less time to lose foreign affixes and become naturalized. The earliest citations for *Spaniard* in the Oxford English Dictionary are from around the fifteenth century, while the earliest for *Latino* is 1946.

The continued use of these terms by bilingual speakers, as you have mentioned, is also likely to play a role in the maintenance of the gender distinctions. *Pinoy* and *Pinay* in particular seem to me to be used most often by Filipinos or people of Filipino ancestry, rather than by other English speakers.

Comment: I for one have never heard the word _Pinay_ before. I’ve heard _Pinoy_ many times, but never _Pinay_. Didn’t even know it existed.

Comment: I think you're right about the bilingual users of these terms. I'd add that Latino/a, Pinoy/ay, and similar terms (Chicano/a, F(P)ilipino/a, etc.) are meant to be reflective of how members of the groups in question self-identify. As such, it makes sense that they would retain gender distinctions if group members regularly employ the gendered terms (whether or not they or others are actually bilingual). Compare the older, less-favored term *Hispanic*, which does not inflect for gender.

Answer (score 7):

*-man* and *-woman* are not like the *-o* and *-a* of Romance languages. They are not inflections. They are compounds, not suffixes, and they are not even strictly parallel. *Man* was originally a word for *person* (genderless) and is still found filling that role in many words, though it has also gained a common secondary meaning of *male person*.

Comment: Good point about _-woman_: I'm familiar with the etymology, Old English _wif_ “woman” + _man_ “person.” That explains why _Engliscman_ is Old English and _Englishwoman_ Middle English. That makes the latter half of my question less about gender and more about why the _–man_ “person” suffix is mandatory for some demonyms (_Englishman_), optional for some (_Scot/sman_), and unused for others (_Italian_). The Wikipedia article suggests that the _-man_ suffix corresponds to tribes, but that doesn't quite jibe.