# What is the future for the Word *"Womyn"*?

Tags: etymology, language-evolution, lexicon, feminine

The Word *"womyn"* has an interesting and debated history. It has become ever more pertinent since it's creation. My question is: Does *"womyn"* have a future?

Comment: I think this is too opinion based to ask here.

Comment: Yes, it will have a bright future if many people agree to use it. I don't.

Comment: What do you think? And how will you know what is the best answer to choose from? The person who says *yes* or the one that says *no*?

Comment: Related question about the connotations of "womyn": http://english.stackexchange.com/q/104508/14073

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Ngram, the usage of the term "womyn" is still increasing, so it will be probably be used for the foreseeable future, expecially in feminist contexts:

[Womyn](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/womyn):

> - women (used chieflyin feminist literature as an alternative spelling to avoid the suggestion of sexism perceived in the sequence m-e-n).

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=womyn&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwomyn%3B%2Cc0):  ***womyn***.